# Error while importing dae file of animated character

Tags: xcode6, scenekit

I prepared a mesh with 3dsmax , and export it to collada file and xcode accept it. But I uploaded this mesh to Mixamo.com to make the bones and animation. After that I downloaded the dae file and clone it to the xcode project but xcode make an error message that says: /scntool: failed to convert file with failure reason *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil.

What is the problem?